Проблемы при объявлении переменной
print(d, z, h, "hour", m, "min" , s, "sec")
if d-(d//10*10) == 1:
z = "день"
if d-(d//10*10) == [2,3,4]:
z = "дня"
if d-(d//10*10) >= 5:
z = "дней"

Когда я запускаю программу с этим кодом (здесь представлен лишь его отрывок) пишет name "z" is not defined. Помогите исправить эту ошибку

В коде, который вы прикрепили впринципе много синтаксических ошибок: не соблюдаются отступы, переменные d,z,h,m,s вообще не определены в коде. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить - непонятно.

Вы сначала выводите переменную z, а потом пытаетесь её определить в синтаксически неправильных операторах if.  К тому же хромает логика при определении формы слова день/дня/дней -- для значений d в диапазоне [11...14] должно выводиться дней.

Проверьте в отладчике для каких значений d выражение d-(d//10*10) == [2,3,4] истинно?

if d-(d//10*10) in  [2,3,4]:

def skl(n: int, v: list) -> str:
    if n >= 100:
        n %= 100

    if 5 <= n <= 20:
        return v[2]

    n %= 10
    if n >= 5 or n == 0:
        return v[2]
    elif 2 <= n <= 4:
        return v[1]
    return v[0]


for d in range(30):
    print(d, skl(d, ['день', 'дня', 'дней']))


0 дней
1 день
2 дня
3 дня
4 дня
5 дней
6 дней
7 дней
8 дней
9 дней
10 дней
11 дней
12 дней
13 дней
14 дней
15 дней
16 дней
17 дней
18 дней
19 дней
20 дней
21 день
22 дня
23 дня
24 дня
25 дней
26 дней
27 дней
28 дней
29 дней


Не стоит делать чужую домашку, особенно если это не отвечает на поставленный вопрос )

@Kromster я собираю потерянное время.
